# Puzzle move maximum number from start rows to end rows in a grid of rooms and corridors

Tags: python, algorithm

I have this puzzle that provides a grid of rooms connected together with corridors, in the entrances rooms there are groups of people that you need to move them through the corridors to the exit rooms, the puzzle has the following rules:

1. The grid element path[A][B] = C describes that the corridor going
   from A to B can fit C number of people at each time step.
2. There are at most 50 rooms connected by the corridors and at most 2000000
   people that will fit at a time.
3. entrances and exits never
   overlap.

So I need to find out how many people can fit through at a time in each direction of every corridor in between. For example to solve the following grid:

```
entrances = [0, 1]
exits = [4, 5]
grid = [
    [0, 0, 4, 6, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]
```

In each time step, the following might happen:

- 0 sends 4/4 people to 2 and 6/6 people to 3
- 1 sends 4/5 people to 2 and 2/2 people to 3
- 2 sends 4/4 people to 4 and 4/4 people to 5
- 3 sends 4/6 people to 4 and 4/6 people to 5

So, in total, 16 people could make it to the exit rows at 4 and 5 at each time step.  (Note that in this example, room 3 could have sent any variation of 8 people to 4 and 5, such as 2/6 and 6/6, but the final answer remains the same.)

I tried to solve it by starting from top and moving people down the grid through the next available corridor in the next room until I reach the exits then I count the number of people that reached the exits. This works for simple cases like the example above but it doesn't take into account the best corridor to choose from multiple available corridors in a one room that would allow the maximum number of people to pass through to exits, also it doesn't consider that you can send any combination of people from any room. This is the code I have so far:

```
grid2 = [
#    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
    [0, 0, 4, 6, 0, 9, 8, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0], # 0
    [0, 0, 5, 2, 7, 0, 9, 9, 0, 6, 0, 0], # 1
    [0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 9, 0, 2, 8, 0, 8, 0], # 2
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 1, 8, 0, 7, 0, 9], # 3
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 9, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0], # 4
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 6, 0, 4, 9, 0], # 5
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 2, 3, 6, 1], # 6
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9], # 7
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 6, 2], # 8
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 6], # 9
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], # 10
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], # 11
]

def solve (entrances, exits, path):
    rows = len (path)
    cols = len (path[0])
    station = [x for x in path]
    for r in range (rows):
        for c in range (cols):
            if path[r][c]:
                val = station[r][c]
                station[r][c] = [val, val] if r in entrances else [val, 0]
    total = 0
    for r in [x for x in range (rows) if x not in exits]:
        for c in range (cols):
            if station[r][c] and station[r][c][1]:
                count = station[r][c][1]
                if c not in exits:
                    for i in range (cols):
                        if station[c][i] and not station[c][i][1]: 
                                num = min (count, station[c][i][0])
                                station[c][i][1] = num
                                break
                else: total += count
    return total
```

What's the best approach to solve this puzzle and is there a good algorithm to implement here?

Comment: Please clarify:    

1. This 'grid' by your definition is not a 'grid', but an incidence matrix with edge capacity in every field, right?    

2. Can we assume that any person takes 1 unit of time to pass an edge and once they've cleared it the edge gets that capacity back?

Comment: [Dijkstra's Shortest Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) algorithm is a common one. Edit: That might be over kill for your problem also look into [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

Comment: @Tommalla Well not a grid but it should be obvious from the example I provided that it's a 2d array, about the time step thing the puzzle is not clear about it but I think it means you need to work through it room by room like explained in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems a little bit ambiguous, but here's my best attempt:

Max-Flow. Basically what you're trying to do here, judging from the example, is you're trying to find a max-flow for the residual network given to you in that matrix. This is not said in the specification, but it looks like:

1. At any given time people can only be in the corridors - edges (nodes have capacity 0).
2. People can only enter the network in one 'wave'.

Thanks to those you can think of this as if it was a classic flow problem - you have a network of pipes of certain capacities and you're trying to see what the maximum flow of a liquid can be through those at any time.

Apart from the max-flow problem for which you can use a number of popular algorithms, there's one trick to use here.

Since you have multiple entry and exit nodes in your network, you will need to add 2 artificial nodes, let's call them -1 and +inf. They will be 'superentrance' and 'superexit' respectively. -1 will be connected to all the entrances with 'virtual' edges of infinite capacity (you can hardcode it) and similarily all exit nodes will connect to +inf with 'virtual' edges of capacity infinity. This way you can treat -1 and +inf as the only entrance and exit of your network - their capacity will be the same as the min-cut (the bottleneck; the maximum flow at a given time is equal to the min-cut as follows from [Max-flow min-cut theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem)), so adding them will not change the total flow. It will however give you an easy way to have single inputs and outputs of your network as opposed to multiple ones.

As for the choice of the algorithm, it depends on the size of your graph and the structure of it. Here's a [list of popular algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Solutions) - you can pick the one that is good for your case. If your data allows you to do this, you might want to stick with the popular and easier ones like Ford-Fulkerson or Edmonds-Karp, especially that you will find many implementations online.

Comment: If you're only interested in totals, you can also simply replace the entrances and and exits by single nodes.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a total noob in algorithms, how do I create the network and how do I use the `Max-flow min-cut` theory and which one of these numerous `Maximum flow` algorithms should I use? can you possibly provide a practical example and maybe a pseudo code for the algorithm that is suitable for this puzzle it would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Judging by your input size from your original post I would say go ahead an implement [Ford-Fulkerson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm). The pseudocode is on wikipedia and you can find a ton of implementations online by simply searching for 'Ford Fulkerson python'.